# MYSQL: Index keyword in create table and when to use it

Tags: mysql

What does `index` keyword mean and what function it serves? I understand that it is meant to speed up querying, but I am not very sure how this can be done.

When how to choose the column to be indexed?

A sample of `index` keyword usage is shown below in `create table` query:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_comment`
(
    `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `blog_post_id` INTEGER,
    `author` VARCHAR(255),
    `email` VARCHAR(255),
    `body` TEXT,
    `created_at` DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `blog_comment_FI_1` (`blog_post_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `blog_comment_FK_1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`blog_post_id`)
        REFERENCES `blog_post` (`id`)
)Type=MyISAM
```

;

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'd recommend reading [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) from the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/).  It states that indexes are used...

- To find the rows matching a `WHERE` clause quickly.
- To eliminate rows from consideration.
- To retrieve rows from other tables when performing joins.
- To find the `MIN()` or `MAX()` value for a specific indexed column.
- To sort or group a table (under certain conditions).
- To optimize queries using only indexes without consulting the data rows.

Indexes in a database work like an index in a book.  You can find what you're looking for in an book quicker, because the index is listed alphabetically.  Instead of an alphabetical list, MySQL uses [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) to organize its indexes, which is quicker for its purposes (but would take a lot longer for a human).

Using more indexes means using up more space (as well as the overhead of maintaining the index), so it's only really worth using indexes on columns that fulfil the above usage criteria.

In your example, the `id` and `blog_post_id` columns both uses indexes (`PRIMARY KEY` is an index too) so that the application can find them quicker.  In the case of `id`, it is likely that this allows users to modify or delete a comment quickly, and in the case of `blog_post_id`, so the application can quickly find all comments for a given post.

You'll notice that there is no index for the `email` column.  This means that searching for all blog posts by a particular e-mail address would probably take quite a long time.  If searching for all comments by a particular e-mail address is something you'd want to add, it might make sense to add an index to that too.

Answer (score 4):

This keyword means that you are creating an index on column `blog_post_id` along with the table.

Queries like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM blog_comment
WHERE blog_post_id = @id
```

will use this index to search on this field and run faster.

Also, there is a `foreign key` on this column.

When you decide to delete a blog post, the database will need check against this table to see there are no orphan comments. The index will also speed up this check, so queries like

```
DELETE
FROM blog_post
WHERE ...
```

will also run faster.